# File not found while looping through folder of .txt files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I wrote a program to loop through a folder of text files, and for each one, read it and write its edited contents to a new txt file. When I write to a new file, I add "JSP" to the file name, and so I included an if statement to avoid editing a file with JSP in its name. It gives me an error message that suggests that it tried to do the method writeToFile on a JSP file, and it couldn't be found within the folder. This confuses me because

1. if it's looping through the files and gets to that specific file, it should exist, and
2. it shouldn't even enter the if statement if it has "JSP" in its filename.

Any ideas?

```
import program
import os

def main():
    directoryStr = "/Users/Elle/Documents/TMR/txtfiles/untitled folder"
    directory = os.fsencode(directoryStr)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if ".txt" in filename and "JSP" not in filename:
            storedProcedure = program.StoredProcedure(filename)
            storedProcedure.writeToFile()
main()
```

```
newFile = open(self.newName + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf16")
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'JSP_Pgm_JpgmAPARCustSummary_Ctrl_Pay/Rec_summedbycustid_LtorGr0.txt'
```

Comment: @Sheldore I tried that and got the same error and the same number of successfully written docs :/

Comment: The filenames returned from `os.listdir()` are not complete paths, so you need to call `os.path.join(directory, filename)` on each one to get it. Alternatively, you could use `glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.txt"))` which will return complete paths (and eliminate the need for checking for `".txt"` in your `if` statement).

Comment: @martineau After I tried the glob, it said: raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None
TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

Comment: @martineau Also, I wasn't sure how to use the os.path.join(directory, filename) because I don't have access to the variable filename before I enter the for loop.

Comment: I meant do it _in_ the loop, where you do have a `filename`. Just use `directoryStr` instead of `directory`—I don't think you need the `os.fsencode()`.

Comment: So what's the purpose of os.path.join(directory, filename)? What should I replace with it?

Comment: I meant replace it with `os.path.join(directoryStr, filename)`.

Comment: I can't replace os.path.join(directory, filename) with os.path.join(directoryStr, filename) because os.path.join(directory, filename) is not currently in my code. If you could be a little more clear.

Comment: Sorry, use `os.path.join(directoryStr, file)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing things this way — as I said in a comment, `os.listdir()` only gives you a list of filenames, not complete file paths.

```
import program
import os

def main():
    directory = "/Users/Elle/Documents/TMR/txtfiles/untitled folder"

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if ".txt" in filename and "JSP" not in filename:
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            storedProcedure = program.StoredProcedure(filepath)
            storedProcedure.writeToFile()

main()
```

Comment: @ElleSzabo: Are you sure you changed the `storeProcedure = program.StoreProcedure(filepath)` line? If so, then there's something going on in `program.StoreProcedure()` I don't understand—and you haven't included the code for that).

Comment: yeah I copied and pasted.  Ok, I'll take a look. if you want me to email the code i can.

Comment: @Elle: No, I don't want you to email me the code. Even if you're still getting a `FileNotFoundError` might be the same, but name following the `No such file or directory:` should now be different than it was before—right?

Comment: now I'm getting an error on the line that writes to a file-- "    newFile = open(self.newName + ".txt", "w", encoding=encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'JSP_Pgm_JpgmAPARCustSummary_Ctrl_Pay/Rec_summedbycustid_LtorGr0.txt'"

Comment: That's interesting, because it doesn't look like changing the value of the argument passed to the `program.StoreProcedure()` function affected anything (because the file or directory not found is exactly the same as before. This leads me to believe the bug is in that function, not the code you posted in your question — although I still think the changes shown in my answer should be made. You need to debug `program.StoreProcedure()`.